# How to assign the limited candy to the kids?

Tags: algorithm

We want to share the candy with the kids.

Say we have m different kind of candy a_1, ..., a_m.

For each type of candy, the amount is q_j, where j = 1,...,m.

There are n kids, c_1, ..., c_n.

Since the amount of candy is limited, each kid c_i would be offered a set of candy A_i, where A_i is any combination of a_1, ..., a_m and |A_i|>=1.

Goal: assign each kid exactly one of his favorites candy. If the kid doesn't pick any kind of candy from A_i (i.e. they pick from the rest kind of candy), we have to give them a bar of chocolate. Within the certain amount of candy, we want to minimize the number of chocolate given to the kids.

How to solve the problem in O(mn^2) time?

Comment: Any example...?

Comment: you can model this as a max flow problem. you have a source node, and that source node has edges into nodes representing type of candy, the capacity of the edge being the quantity of that amount of candy. then you have a second set of nodes representing the children. edges of capacity 1 are directed from each candy type to each child that wants that candy type. then each child has an edge into one sink node. the maximum flow from the source to the sink is the maximum number of children you can satisfy

Comment: @Yash No example provided.

Comment: @Primusa That's what I thought. But seems like candy will not share an endpoint in the children group, but children share endpoint in the candy since several children could pick the same type of candy. That makes it not a bipartite matching problem.

Comment: i didn't propose bipartite matching. maximum flow is a tool can be used to solve bipartite matching, and it can be used to solve this one. a lot of different problems can be solved with max flow, not just bipartite matching.

Comment: to illustrate why max flow also works when multiple children can choose one type of candy:

imagine you have one type of candy `c`, which you have 100 copies of, and 10 children which all prefer that candy `c`. the resulting graph consists of one source node with an edge of 100 units of capacity going into a node representing candy `c`. then `c` has is connected to 10 different nodes, representing the 10 children. there is an edge of capacity 1 going from `c` into each node that represents a child, indicating that that child prefers `c`.

Comment: each child node then has an edge into the sink. its easy to see that the maximum flow through this system is 10, where 10 units of flow goes into `c`, and then one unit of flow goes from `c` into each of the children, and this is correct, because up to 10 children can be satisfied, successfully modeling many children -> one candy type